# Python instanceof on alias type

Tags: python, types

I have the following types and type alias defined:

```py
@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 4

class A:
    pass


class B:
    pass

MyAlias = MyEnum | A | B

MyAlias2 = MyAlias | str | int

@dataclass(slots=True)
class A:
    type: MyAlias2
```

If I do `isinstance` check like so:

```py
a = A()
isintance(a, MyAlias)
```

it returns `False`.

I understand that it happens because I redefine the class later, but I do this because I first need to define what is a type of type `MyAlias` so I could later define what is `MyAlias2` to then be able to use it as an attribute inside class `A`. Now obviously since we're in python I could just not define the attributes of class `A` and make a constructor that accept whatever, but since I'm thinking about portability in the future, and also I do want the "benefits" of type hinting right now, I do it this way and I wonder what can I do to make the `isinstance` report `True` in such case where there's circular dependency between what is defined first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `A` first and use a string as the typehint.

```
@dataclass(slots=True)
class A:
    type: 'MyAlias'

MyAlias = MyEnum | A | B
```

Comment: I don't know this use case, does it let me use type hinting for later defined type?

Comment: @Jorayen Yes, type checkers (like Mypy) do handle forward references like these.

Comment: If I add `from __future__ import annotations` can I do this without string?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyAlias = Union[MyEnum, A, B]
MyAlias2 = Union[MyAlias, str, int]

a = A()
isinstance_a = isinstance(a, A)# returns True
isinstance_union = isinstance(a, (MyEnum, A, B))#returns True
```

Instead of checking for instance against combination of type the check here is allowed to go 1 by 1

Comment: interesting but still I would prefer to use the alias incase it changes the types in the future :)